# Apache POI: Indexed Color from AWT Color input

Tags: java, colors, apache-poi, awt

I am trying to replicate font and color from a given `java.awt.Color` and `java.awt.Font` in my Excel file created using apache POI. The latter works, however setting the color does not: while my fonts in Excel are colored green when directly set so by using `IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex()`, using the `java.awt.Color` to create a `XSSFColor` does not work (see code below). How do i get the (closest) `IndexedColor` or even better use the original value of `java.awt.Color` in my POI font?

Current code snippet:

```
            Font font = workbook.createFont();
            //font.setColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());  //Works
            font.setColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.GREEN).getIndex()); //Does not work

            font.setFontName(getFont(i,j).getFamily());
            font.setFontHeightInPoints((short)getFont(i,j).getSize());
            font.setItalic(getFont(i,j).isItalic());
            font.setBold(getFont(i,j).isBold());
```

(Apache POI 3.17)

Comment: Have you tried font.setColor(new XSSFColor(java.awt.Color.GREEN)) ?

Comment: Just checked to be sure, Font.setFont expects a `short` value (-> error if i try it this way).

Comment: https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFFont.java#L378

Comment: XSSFWorkbook#createFont returns XSSFFont (an implementation of Font) and this XSSFFont class has a setColor(XSSFColor) method.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason my javadoc shows "All Known Implementing Classes: HSSFFont" for `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font`. But XSSFFont also implements it and it works like you said. If you want to put this as answer i will certainly accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSSFWorkbook#createFont returns XSSFFont (an implementation of Font) and this XSSFFont class has a setColor(XSSFColor) method.